# ISomeBaseInterface cannot be inherited with different arguments: <java.lang.Object> and <>

Tags: java, generics

When I compile following code in Eclipse - there are no any errors.
There is only one warning:

> SomeDerivedAbstractClass is a raw type. References to generic type
>   SomeDerivedAbstractClass should be parameterized

I tested this code in the newest Eclipse Indigo(3.7.1).
**But there is following error when I tried to compile this code by javac:**

```
SomeConcreateClass.java:1: ISomeBaseInterface cannot be inherited with different arguments: <java.lang.Object> and <>
public class SomeConcreateClass
       ^
1 error
```

I compiled this code suing Java 5 and Java 6. In both cases there is error.
**What is wrong in this code?**

```
public class SomeConcreateClass
   extends SomeDerivedClass
   implements ISomeInterface
{}

class SomeDerivedClass<T>
    extends SomeAbstractClass<Object>
    implements ISomeInterface
{
}

abstract class SomeAbstractClass<T> 
   implements ISomeBaseInterface<T>
{
}

interface ISomeInterface extends ISomeBaseInterface<Object> 
{}

interface ISomeBaseInterface<T>
{
}
```

But following code does not compile either in Eclipse or by javac:

```
public class SomeConcreateClass
   extends SomeAbstractClass
   implements ISomeInterface
{}

abstract class SomeAbstractClass<T> 
   implements ISomeBaseInterface<Object>
{}

interface ISomeInterface extends ISomeBaseInterface<Object> 
{}

interface ISomeBaseInterface<T>
{}
```

javac:

> SomeConcreateClass.java:1: ISomeBaseInterface cannot be inherited with
>   different arguments:  and <> public class
>   SomeConcreateClass
>          ^ 1 error

Eclipse:

> The interface ISomeBaseInterface cannot be implemented more than once
>   with different arguments: ISomeBaseInterface and
>   ISomeBaseInterface

So - is it a bug in Eclipse?
Is it the same bug as https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=81824 ?

**ONE MORE UPDATE:**
This code compiles without errors both by javac and Eclipse:

```
public class SomeConcreateClass
   extends SomeDerivedClass
   implements ISomeInterface
{}

class SomeDerivedClass
    extends SomeAbstractClass<Object>
    implements ISomeInterface
{}

abstract class SomeAbstractClass<T> 
   implements ISomeBaseInterface<T>
{}

interface ISomeInterface extends ISomeBaseInterface<Object> 
{}

interface ISomeBaseInterface<T>
{}
```

There is only one difference: SomeDerivedClass is not parameterized.
I do not understand how does this influence on ISomeBaseInterface.

**AND ONE MORE UPDATE:**
I checked code from the first example in IntellijIDEA - this IDE shows error.
But I think it uses different approach for compilation than Eclipse.

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? There was a bug allowing this to compile in older versions of Eclipse: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=81824

Comment: MyEclipse 7.5 and Eclipse Galileo.

Comment: I downloaded newest Eclipse Indigo(3.7.1). It compiles this code without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something<> is NOT the same as Something<Object> (even though it might seem like that is reasonable).

SomeAbstractClass<T> implements ISomeBaseInterface<T>, and SomeAbstractClass<> implements ISomeBaseInterface<> So when you use SomeDerivedAbstractClass<> (in SomeConcreateClass), you're asking the class to implement both ISomeConcreateInterface (that is, ISomeBaseInterface<Object>) and ISomeBaseInterface<> at the same time, which it cannot do.

You might want to use SomeDerivedAbstractClass<?>, I think.

Comment: I can get it to compile with "public class SomeConcreateClass extends SomeDerivedAbstractClass<ISomeOtherInterface> implements ISomeInterface". It looks like you need to specify SomeDerivedAbstractClass instead of leaving it as a raw type.

Comment: I cleaned the code a little. It is much shorter now. There is no ISomeOtherInterface now.